# Is it possible to see the source code of a Safari Extension?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extensions

If you install a Safari Extension, are you able to see its source code?
It is great to verify that the extension does not contain malware.

One can do it with Chrome as described in [this blog](https://www.howtogeek.com/198964/HOW-TO-VIEW-THE-SOURCE-CODE-OF-A-CHROME-EXTENSION/)

Comment: Please read: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @anki I haven't answered my question. Please read carefully. I'm asking about Safari, my example refers to Chrome.

Comment: Since safari 13, all extensions are like apps with `.appex` files which are used as extensions. So if you can view source code of any other app (executable) you can see code for those apps too. For extensions released as safariextz files, see https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/

Answer (score 4):

[Source of information](https://www.transpire.com/insights/blog/viewmodify-safari-extension-source-code/):

> 1. Locate the extension. It should be living in your library folder. Note this is a hidden folder so in the finder use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to put in this location `~/Library/Safari/Extensions`.  Here you’ll see the Safari extensions you have installed. They have a `.safariext` file extension, but this is really just a xar file.
> 2. To extract the extension’s files, use this command (replacing the '/path/to' with the correct path and the 'extension.safariextz' with the correct name) `xar -xf /path/to/extension.safariextz` The extension will be extracted into a folder, with the source and resources contained within.
> 3. If you want to change something and then package it back up for
>    reinstallation, you can xar the folder back into a single file using `xar -c -f output.safariextz extensionFolder`.

I'm running 10.15.6 and these steps worked for me.

Since Safari 13, all extensions must be downloaded from the App Store as `.app` bundles with `.appex` files inside them. Both of them are built in Xcode thus you only get the final executable. So if the extension is not open source, you cannot see what's in the binary

A simple way to understand how the app and extension interact, see the following. (Note that it's an Xcode extension, not Safari. )

- https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat/blob/master/XcodeClangFormat/AppDelegate.m
- https://github.com/mapbox/XcodeClangFormat/blob/master/clang-format/ClangFormatCommand.mm

Comment: This doesn't list extensions which come in .app bundles from the App Store like grammaly, or adguard. I only see the legacy extensions there.

Comment: It might not but that was not part of OP's question so I didn't address it.  Feel free to edit my answer to add the missing info.

Comment: I confirm that `~/Library/Safari/Extensions` seems to contain only a small subset of the extensions. Two examples of well known extensions not being present there: Night Eye, AdBlock.

Comment: any idea how to uniquely identify extension metadata from the .app bundle, which I'm assuming lives in `/System/Applications`?